# How to remove nil values from a list in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, depth-first-search

I have written a function DFS that traverses a search tree in a right-to-left, DFS order. For example, (DFS '((((L E) F) T))) should return (T F E L). The following code I created successfully does that, however it still contains NIL values in the result. How can I remove just the nil values?

```
; Following code returns right answer, but with nils.
; For example. running the function on 
; '((((L E) F) T)) will return ((((NIL . T) . F) . E) . L)
; but not (T F E L)

(defun DFS (tree)
  (cond ((null tree) ()) ;current node is null, return nil 
        ;Checks if car of current node is a list. If yes, recursively call DFS and append car to its cdr
        ((listp (car tree)) (DFS (append (car tree) (cdr tree))))
        ;Else, call recursively DFS on cdr of current node and append to car 
        (T (cons (DFS (cdr tree)) (car tree)))))
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to document what the COND clauses should do -> in english. Use comments in the code.

Otherwise we have to guess what your intentions were.

Comment: What should it do with, for instance, ((L E) (F T))? Should it return ((F T) (L E)), ((T F)  (E L)), or (T F E L)?

Comment: here is a hint -> your comment says: 'append to car', but you are not appending, you are calling cons. appending also would need to work on lists.

Answer (score 1):

If your tree is:

```
(LEFT . RIGHT)
```

Then a recursive call to `(DFS RIGHT)` should give you a list of leaves in reverse order in the right tree, let's call it `RL` (right list).

Likewise, calling `(DFS LEFT)` should give you a list of leaves for the left tree, called for example `LL` (left list).

Then, since both of them are lists, you can append them.

In your code, some arguments to `CONS` are not necessarily lists (for the cdr) or non-nil symbols (for the car). There is also a suspicious call to `append` before calling `dfs`, this looks a bit too complicated.

A smaller example would give the following trace:

```
  0: (DFS (A (B)))
    1: (DFS ((B)))
      2: (DFS NIL)
      2: DFS returned NIL
      2: (DFS (B))
        3: (DFS NIL)
        3: DFS returned NIL
        3: (DFS B)
        3: DFS returned (B)
        3: (APPEND NIL (B))
        3: APPEND returned (B)
      2: DFS returned (B)
      2: (APPEND NIL (B))
      2: APPEND returned (B)
    1: DFS returned (B)
    1: (DFS A)
    1: DFS returned (A)
    1: (APPEND (B) (A))
    1: APPEND returned (B A)
  0: DFS returned (B A)
```

---

If you fix that, you may notice that you call `append` a lot, but you are in fact just putting new items in front of a list, one by one. If you could for example pass the list `LL` when computing `(DFS RIGHT)`, then you could directly add elements in front of it, one by one, instead of building intermediate lists and appending them.

This may not be an important gain especially for an exercise but in terms of practicing Lisp, it's nice to try alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use tail call recursion -
the construction then takes place just around `acc`.

It is more idiomatic to test with `atom` than with `listp`.

By the way, `listp` is a little bit problematic.
As you can see: `(listp '(a b))` as well as `(listp '(a . b))` both evalute to `T`. But one would expect the latter one to return `NIL`.
So it is better - would lead to less misunderstandings -  to use `consp` instead of `listp`. And before we discuss long about this topic, it is much better to just use `atom` for the un-misunderstandable case "not a list".

And here you see, how one can get step by step to the right solution: it all depends on where you put `cons` or `append`:

```
(defun dfs (tree &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null tree) (nreverse acc))
        ((atom (car tree)) (dfs (cdr tree) (cons (car tree) acc)))
        (t (dfs (cdr tree) (cons (dfs (car tree)) acc)))))

(dfs '((((L E) F) T)))
;; ((((L E) F) T))
```

Let us not `nreverse` after `cons`-ing:

```
(defun dfs (tree &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null tree) acc)
        ((atom (car tree)) (dfs (cdr tree) (cons (car tree) acc)))
        (t (dfs (cdr tree) (cons (dfs (car tree)) acc)))))

(dfs '((((L E) F) T)))
;; ((T (F (E L))))
```

This looks better. Now, in case of it is a list, we `append` instead of to `cons` to get rid of the unwanted parantheses:

```
(defun dfs (tree &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null tree) acc)
        ((atom (car tree)) (dfs (cdr tree) (cons (car tree) acc)))
        (t (dfs (cdr tree) (append (dfs (car tree)) acc)))))

(dfs '((((L E) F) T)))
;; (T F E L)
```

Voila!